# TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER vs TransactionManagementType.BEAN

Tags: ejb-3.0, spring-transactions, spring-mybatis, transactionmanager

what is the difference between TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER and TransactionManagementType.BEAN

as Im using TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER in all of my EJBs and when ever the multiple instances of database is used, It throws an error which gets resolved if i change it to TransactionManagementType.BEAN

I want to know what are the advantages and disadvantages and how it gets effected if I change it to TransactionManagementType.BEAN

```
ERROR:
Error updating database.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: 
IJ000457: Unchecked throwable in managedConnectionReconnected() cl=org.jboss.jca.core.
connectionmanager.listener.TxConnectionListener@680f2be0[state=NORMAL managed 
connection=org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnection@7ba33a94 connection 
handles=0 lastReturned=1495691675021 lastValidated=1495690817487 
lastCheckedOut=1495691675018 trackByTx=false pool=org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.
pool.strategy.OnePool@efd42c4 mcp=SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedQueueManagedConnectionPool
@71656eec[pool=FAQuery] xaResource=LocalXAResourceImpl@4c786e85
[connectionListener=680f2be0 connectionManager=5c3b98bc warned=false 
currentXid=null productName=Oracle productVersion=Oracle Database 12c 
Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options
jndiName=java:/FAQuery] txSync=null]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER

You let the container itself manage transactions(container will commit and rollback). You can control behavior of your transactions (more precisely transaction propagation) by annotating methods with `@TransactionManagementAttribute` and specifying one of the attributes from [TransactionAttribute Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/TransactionAttributeType.html).

> TransactionManagementType.BEAN

You have to do transaction demarcation (start, commit, rollback) explicitly yourself, by obtaining [UserTransaction](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html) interface.

```
@Resource
UserTransaction ut;

public void method(){
   ut.begin();
... // your business logic here
   ut.commit(); // or ut.rollback();
}
```

Note that you have to either commit and rollback before you exit the same method which stated the transaction for Stateless and Message Driven Beans, but it is not required for Stateful bean.

Regarding your question, advantage of BMT is that scope of the transaction can be less than scope of the method itself, i.e explicit control of the transaction.
You would most probably use CMT, BMT is required only in some narrow corner cases to support specific business logic.
Another advantage or use case of BMT is if you need to use Extended Persistence Context Type, which can be supported in BMT with Stateful Session Beans.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your specific problem, without seeing any bean code or error messages, this is probably what is happening: if you have more databases then each database and its corresponding driver must be able to join an existing transaction, otherwise you will get a specific detailed error.

If you use `TransactionManagementType.BEAN` the bean is required to start a brand new transaction. Which means you are not joining an existing transaction, and each database operations begin and commit independently from each others.

You can achieve the same effect by leaving `TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER` and annotating your method with `REQUIRES_NEW`, provide of course you are calling each EJB trough the corresponding proxy/interface.

So it is not correct to put it like BEAN vs CONTAINER, but rather you have to made some design choice and annotate your methods accordingly.

As requested for a method marked with one of the following:

- REQUIRES_NEW existing transactions gets suspended, and the method runs under a brand new transaction
- REQUIRED is the default behavior, if a transaction exists it is reused by the method, otherwise gets created and the method runs in it

Comment: May i know what does REQUIRES_NEW and REQUIRED annotation actually means in the code?

Comment: and btw im not using different databases but two different instances(datasource) of the same database

Comment: it is the same issue: If the datasource and its underlying database and driver cannot join an existing transaction the client will get an error, unless you mark your EJB method with `REQUIRED_NEW` or `NOT_SUPPORTED`

Comment: I tried using REQUIRED_NEW with TransactionManagementType as CONTAINER but getting the same error. I have updated the error in the question, please have a look at it